# How does DATEDIFF calculate week differences in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, idioms, datediff

I would like to calculate the difference in *weeks* between two dates, where two dates are considered part of the same week if their preceding Sunday is the same. Ideally, I'd like to do this using `DATEDIFF`, instead of learning an elaborate idiom to calculate the value. But I can't tell how it works when weeks are involved.

The following query returns 1 and 2. This might make sense if your calendar week begins with a Sunday, i.e. if you run `SET DATEFIRST 7` beforehand or if `@@DATEFIRST` is 7 by default.

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
-- SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE
    @d1 DATETIME,
    @d2a DATETIME,
    @d2b DATETIME
;
SELECT
    @d1 = '2010-04-05',   -- Monday
    @d2a = '2010-04-16',  -- Following Friday
    @d2b = '2010-04-18'   -- the Sunday following
;

SELECT
    DATEDIFF(week, @d1, @d2a) AS weekdiff_a   -- returns 1
    ,DATEDIFF(week, @d1, @d2b) AS weekdiff_b  -- returns 2
;
```

So I expected different results if `SET DATEFIRST 1` is executed instead of `SET DATEFIRST 7`. But the return values are the same, regardless!

What is going on here? What should I do to get the correct week differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DATEDIFF doesn't respect the DATEFIRST setting.

Here's a similar question, with a potential workaround:

[Is it possible to set start of week for T-SQL DATEDIFF function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101892/is-it-possible-to-set-start-of-week-for-t-sql-datediff-function)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. With your help, I was able to find a defensible solution to my problem.