# SQL Server : group by week off by 1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the syntax

```
dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)
```

to group data by week it appears that the last day of the week gets put into the following week.

In a simple example

```
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '27 jan 2012 00:00'),0)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '28 jan 2012 00:00'),0)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '29 jan 2012 00:00'),0)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '30 jan 2012 00:00'),0)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '31 jan 2012 00:00'),0)
```

I would expect to return

```
Jan 23 2012 12:00AM
Jan 23 2012 12:00AM
Jan 23 2012 12:00AM
Jan 30 2012 12:00AM
Jan 30 2012 12:00AM
```

or

```
Jan 22 2012 12:00AM
Jan 22 2012 12:00AM
Jan 29 2012 12:00AM
Jan 29 2012 12:00AM
Jan 29 2012 12:00AM
```

depending on DATEFIRST settings I guess

however it returns

```
Jan 23 2012 12:00AM
Jan 23 2012 12:00AM
Jan 30 2012 12:00AM
Jan 30 2012 12:00AM
Jan 30 2012 12:00AM
```

i.e. the 29 January is in the week of 30th January not 23rd January or 30th January as expected.

I'm clearly missing something but can't think what it might be.

Comment: Sure, the point is though that it appears to be inconsistent with itself

Comment: I read up on 'set datefirst' and saw that you already knew about "first day of week", so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct.

No matter what `@@DATEFIRST` is, there is always the same number of whole weeks between now and 01 Jan 1900. As `@@DATEFIRST` changes, it affects *both* "start" and "end" week.

DATEADD then just adds 7 day periods because it ignores @@DATEFIRST

You can force it by choosing the DATEADD base

Example: 01 Jan 1900 is a Monday.

You want Sunday? Then base to 31 Dec 1899

```
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '27 jan 2012 00:00'),-1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '28 jan 2012 00:00'),-1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '29 jan 2012 00:00'),-1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '30 jan 2012 00:00'),-1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '31 jan 2012 00:00'),-1)
```

You want Tuesday? Then base to 02 Jan 1900

```
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '27 jan 2012 00:00'),1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '28 jan 2012 00:00'),1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '29 jan 2012 00:00'),1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '30 jan 2012 00:00'),1)
print dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '31 jan 2012 00:00'),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should convert the date to the first day of the week for the purposes of grouping

```
set datefirst 1
select dateadd(day, -1 * (datepart(weekday, getdate()) - 1), getdate())
```

Note that the `set datefirst 1` sets the first day of the week as Monday. You can alter this statement to change the first day of the week to fit to your expectations (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Comment: I think that's incorrect. `DATEDIFF()` doens't see the `DATEFIRST`value.

Comment: Thanks Andy, guess I was hoping there was a 'catch all' syntax of grouping by day, week month etc. but I guess not.

Comment: @aF. That is why I'm not using DATEDIFF :-)

Comment: I think maybe aF has the 'reason' which is why Andy presented the correct answer. All sorted now, thanks again.

Comment: Ah, one point I missed was that I wanted to not only group by week but also return the date as the start of that week, @gbn's solution does that also

Comment: Indeed gbn's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF doesn't respect the DATEFIRST setting.

Here's a similar question, with a potential workaround:

[Is it possible to set start of week for T-SQL DATEDIFF function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101892/is-it-possible-to-set-start-of-week-for-t-sql-datediff-function)