# datediff inside the time schedule

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I need to calculate datedif(ss, start_time, end_time) between certain types of activities, which I pretty know how to do it. My code is:

```
WITH WorkDates AS (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.NUMBER ORDER BY datestamp DESC) AS RowNumber,
    p2.affected_item as Service,
    p1.close_time as close_time,
    datestamp,
    description,
    a.type,
    a.number as number
from ACTIVITYM1 a
left outer join probsummarym1 p1 on a.number = p1.number
inner join probsummarym2 p2 on p1.number = p2.number
where ((a.type like 'status%'
and (description like '%to Work In Progress%'
or description like '%from Work In Progress%'))  or a.type like 'Closed')
)
SELECT
O1.Service,
O1.number,
O1.close_time,
    sum(DATEDIFF(ss, O2.datestamp, O1.datestamp)) AS sum_of_time
FROM WorkDates O1
LEFT JOIN WorkDates O2
    ON O2.RowNumber = O1.RowNumber + 1
    and O2.number = O1.number
where O2.description like '%to Work In Progress%' 
and (O1.description like '%from Work In Progress%' or O1.type like 'Closed')
group by O1.Service, O1.number, O1.close_time
order by O1.Service, O1.number
```

I'm doing it that way, because I need to calculate it between certain types of activities, and a number of such 'time windows' where it should be counted is not constant. And it works quite ok, but it calculates full time, including holidays, weekends

But there is one one more thing I need to have done here.

I would like to calculate datediff(ss, start_date, end_date) but only from Monday to Friday. It means, for example if start_date was on Friday at 16:00 and end_date on Monday at 7:00, datediff should be (24:00 - 16:00) + (07:00 - 00:00) = 15 hours. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate week difference, then convert it to seconds, then deduct it from datediff. 
Like this:

```
sum(DATEDIFF(ss, O2.datestamp, O1.datestamp) - abs(DATEPART(ww,O2.datestamp) - DATEPART(ww,O1.datestamp)) * 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) AS sum_of_time
```

Comment: one more little question, what about such code: sum(DATEDIFF(ss, O2.datestamp, O1.datestamp) - DATEDIFF(ww, O2.datestamp, O1.datestamp) * 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) AS sum_of_time  are there any contraindications for not using it ?

Comment: Yes, this code looks better than mine! But check DATEFIRST http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101892/is-it-possible-to-set-start-of-week-for-t-sql-datediff-function

Comment: Yep that's important too ;)  But reason to use datediff for weeks rather than abs was, that for dates between two different years it didn't calculate it correctly ;) But thanks anyway to give me idea how to solve this :)